# Changing flight times and limited time to transit at Singapore (from UK to NZ)

Tags: air-travel, transit, airlines, singapore

I'm booked on a flight from Heathrow to NZ via Singapore. 
  The original transfer time was 2 hours, but has since reduced to 90 minutes. 
 Will this be enough? 
The UK to Singapore leg is using Singapore Airlines (run by air new Zealand) and the Singapore to nz leg by air nz.
 I'm assuming baggage transfer will be automatic, but am concerned about having time to move from terminal 0(?) to terminal 3

Comment: Are both flights on the same ticket?

Comment: Thanks! I only have one booking reference. How would I know if I have more than one ticket?

Comment: With a single booking reference you should be fine unless it's through Kiwi.com with "Connection guaranteed by Kiwi" or some other shady website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single ticket, 90 minutes is plenty, if there are no major delays. You will be coming in either in Terminal 2 or 3 and departing from Terminal 3. Even if you come in at Terminal 2 you can take the Skytrain, which is quick and easy.

See https://www.changiairport.com/en/airport-guide/transport/transfer-between-terminals-and-jewel.html

Comment: Thanks @hilmar. Any idea of the procedure if we miss the connection because of a delay?

Comment: If it's a single ticket, the operating carrier will rebook you for free on the next available flight. This may be the next day. In this case you may be entitled for hotel & food cost but that depends on a lot of different factors

Comment: There are a lot of things much worse than having to stay a night at Changi airport, especially since you can probably pass immigration (depends on your nationality) and check out things like [Jewel](https://www.visitsingapore.com/en_au/travel-guide-tips/travelling-to-singapore/changi-airport-singapore/jewel-changi-airport/) just outside immigration.

Comment: Be mindful of recent restrictions on view of COVID-19. Visitors are not allowed transit as of now.